# Dynamically change the class attribute of jasper's textFieldExpression

Tags: java, excel, jasper-reports

I have to display a `textField` a jasper report. The report is generated to an Excel file. The problem is with a particular column which sometimes has a string and sometimes has an integer (also as string). When it has an integer as string, Excel complains that there is a number stored as text in that particular cell. I would like to display the number as a number, not as a string.

How can I dynamically change the `class` attribute of the `textFieldExpression` to be `java.lang.Integer` when the string is a valid number?
Or is another other way to insert a condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two fields and a `PrintWhenExpression` that will determine the appropriate field to display.